# How to add support for more than one Thymeleaf template modes

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot app using Thymeleaf 3 as the template engine for the app pages. We use the default configuration provided by *spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf*, with the HTML Thymeleaf templates under the *src/main/resources/templates* folder.

Now we would like to use Thymeleaf to generate also some javascript files, using the new javascript template mode. Those javascript templates could be located into the same HTML templates folder or another one (ex: *src/main/resources/jstemplates*).

I don't know if there is a way to add this configuration without changing anything in the default configuration provided by the *spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf*, or I have to create a full configuration for everything.

I've tried the first option with the following configuration, which works for the javascript templates, but then html templates don't work anymore.

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

  @Autowired
  private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

  @Autowired
  private ThymeleafProperties properties;

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Bean
  public ThymeleafViewResolver javascriptThymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
    resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".js"});
    resolver.setCache(this.properties.isCache());
    return resolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jstemplates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".js");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

A test javascript controller:

```
@Controller
public class JavascriptController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test.js")
  public String testjs() {
    return "test";
  }
}
```

The controller for the root page:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
  public String index(Model model) {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

There is a *test.js* file in the *src/main/resources/jstemplates* folder. If I try the url http://localhost:8080/test.js, it works as expected. But if I try, for example, the main url (http://localhost:8080/) it fails with the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [jstemplates/index.js] cannot be opened because it does not exist

It should be looking for the *templates/index.html* instead, so it seems the *javascriptTemplateResolver* overrides or takes precedence over de default one, without falling back to it.

Is there a way to add another template mode support integrated with the default Thymeleaf configuration, or I need to configure everything from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some debugging I finally found the solution. It seems the *SpringResourceTemplateResolver* doesn't check by default if the template really exists. In my example configuration, the first template resolver is the one configured for the javascript templates, and it was creating a *View* without looking first if the template exists.

To solve it the template *checkExistence* property must be set to *true*. Ex:

```
  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jstemplates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".js");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    return resolver;
  }
```

The only problem I see with this configuration is that if we create a js view with the same name as a html view, it will always get the javascript one.

**Edit**

To solve that last issue I've made some changes in the configuration:

- Remove the *.js* suffix in the resolver configuration
- When a controller gives a javascript view name, that name already includes the *.js* suffix.

The final configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

  @Autowired
  private ThymeleafProperties properties;

  @Autowired
  private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Bean
  public ThymeleafViewResolver javascriptThymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
    resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.js"});
    resolver.setCache(this.properties.isCache());
    return resolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/js/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    resolver.setCacheable(this.properties.isCache());
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

And the sample controller:

```
@Controller
public class JavascriptController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/js/test.js")
  public String testjs() {
    return "test.js";
  }
}
```

The HTML view controllers remain unchanged.